# using the openpyxl python library, I want to know the coordinates where each entry of data is being inserted

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is because I would like to merge cells according to the data, if the first column is related to the second one, but I don't know how much data the second one will have because it may be different, I want to merge the first one to match the second one.

The other option that I like less, is to check column 2, 3, 4, etc, and knowing which is the largest, combine the first column to match, but it seems to me that it would not be very efficient to process folders (and subfolders) of 20 thousand files approximately.

I am trying to figure out the row in which column range (from A1 to A10, for example) I need to merge.

Comment: You will have to show us an example, because your example doesn't make sense.  Clearly, you KNOW where each "entry of data" is, because you only get the data when you ask for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, fortunately for this application, I know what is the maximum number of rows in each group, then each time it processes a file with documents, it simply adds 'n' amount to the counters that will know the next cells to merge, I copy it to help if someone was looking for something similar:

```
def runmerge():
    global row_start, row_end
    coords = (f'A{row_start}:A{row_end}')
    ws.merge_cells(coords)
    coords = (f'B{row_start}:B{row_end}')
    ws.merge_cells(coords)
    coords = (f'C{row_start}:C{row_end}')
    ws.merge_cells(coords)
    coords = (f'D{row_start}:D{row_end}')
    ws.merge_cells(coords)
    coords = (f'O{row_start}:O{row_end}')
    ws.merge_cells(coords)
    row_start += 5
    row_end += 5

row_start = 2
row_end = 6
```

Start at position 2 to skip the header.